# Youtube is not working on my computer for the past few days?

Tags: video, youtube

I am trying to use Youtube and it's not working. I got this code in view-source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head
  <title>
  </title>
</head>
<body>

  <!--This is a comment. Comments are not displayed in the browser-->

</body>
</html>
```

Does someone know waht the trouble is? Most of the videos work while some others do not. I have seen this fort the past few days.[image]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall not under your control?

Comment: No, I am using my own Computer. I am Located in Agra India. Most of time When I visit Forum I got alert for whitelist my IP first. My ip is dynamic. Not sure if some bad guys have used these IP I got :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Had to disable cache and hard-refresh multiple times to actually get it to load. Maybe this is India specific problem?

Comment: change the url from http to https and see if it works.

Comment: @harsh.prasad This is work fine now. That time BSNL got a problem. Maybe that is fixed for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, trying issuing the command `ping youtube.com` and check the IP address.  The common IP scheme you should look for is:

- 74.125.X.X

Check your HOSTS file.  It almost looks like the YouTube URL is being redirected to a different server (looks local, but can't really tell).

Windows Location: %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\

Linux is generally in \etc

You might also want to check your router (if you have one) as you can also redirect traffic through that.

Comment: I am on Windows 8 and I have posted the image in question. thanks for help